# Multiplication of Power Series [Complex]

Tags: power-series, formal-power-series

I know that given two power series, $A$ and $B$, such that $A= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ and $B= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n$
then,

$AB= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i*b_{n-i})x^n$

But then I was wondering, if $A$ is of the form $A= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  a_n x^{mn}$ and $B= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n$ for some $m \in [2,3,...]$
then,

Will the product of A and B, be

$AB= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i*b_{n-i})x^{mn}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In the first formula, where did the exponent on $x$ come from? 
(Further hint: it's the sum of the indices of $a$ and $b$) Why?

Have you tried a concrete example, with finite power series (i.e., polynomials) and $m = 2$? For instance, have you checked out the case

$$
A = 3x^2 + 2 x^4 + 11 x^6 \\
B = 1 + 3x + 2x^2
$$
by explicitly comparing your two formulas?

Answer (score 0):

No, otherwise your power series would contain only powers with multiples of $m$ which is clearly wrong.

I don't see a "nice" closed form besides
$$\sum_n \left(\sum_{mi+j=n} a_ib_j\right) x^n=\sum_n \left(\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/m\rfloor} a_ib_{n-mi}\right) x^n$$